# Docker-Compose can't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect Django project with MySQL using docker.

I have the problem when upping docker-compose. It says the next error:

> super(Connection, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs2)
>   django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

I'm using port 3307, should i create first new database schema in my local? Or how can I do it because my default port is 3306 but if i try to use it, it says that is busy.

My code here:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN apt-get update
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

Docker-compose

```
    version: '2'

services:
  app:
    container_name: container_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py migrate && python manage.py shell < backend/scripts/setup.py && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    container_name: container_database
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: 'host.docker.internal'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'container_develop'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"
```

settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database_develop',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3307,
        'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        'COLLATION': 'utf8_bin',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_unicode' : True,
            'init_command': 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED',
        },
    }
}
```

The thing is that I do not have the database anywhere so I'm using it locally, do I have to upload the db to a server and then use the port that server provides to me?
Is there any way to use it locally from docker? Or installing it to docker? So I can share that docker to a friend and he can use the same DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @Nico answer my fixed your service accessibility from outside of the container, mean if try to access it from the host it should work.

But the error will arise during service to service communication. You should not use publish port in service to service communication or another word you must use container port in service to service communication.

Change the port in connection from `3307` to `3306`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'database_develop',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        'COLLATION': 'utf8_bin',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_unicode' : True,
            'init_command': 'SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx @Adiii it works!! Now i have this error: database | 2019-10-15 16:35:09 13 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.19.0.1' (using password: NO) Should i do anything special to solve it? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean? I have the same pass in docker-compose and in settings

Comment: if the issue still persists try to add `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` . i can verified the connection

Comment: ```var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'db',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'container_develop'
});
``` in nodejs it worked for me

Comment: Thx man! It works but now i restarted docker with docker system prune --all, and now i'm trying to build it again with docker build . And i have the next error en dockerfile (received unexpected HTTP status: 503 Service Unavailable). Do you know why? Thanks man!

Comment: seems like you are using Nginx proxy and the service not responding to Nginx?

Comment: Nope, i'm using the same setup that i show before. I don't have nginx :'(

Comment: It crashes when execute this line Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200912/discussion-between-adiii-and-axel-ros).

Answer (score 4):

In the "db" part, in your docker-compose :

```
ports:
  - "3307:3306"
```

Comment: thx for your answer @Nico, i still have the same error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db' (115)")

Comment: @Adiii seems to have found the solution